# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') in javascript chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building chrome extensions using javascript. I have some struggles on addEventListeners. Kindly check the below code

```
var SpellCheck = document.getElementById('spellCheck')

SpellCheck.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  });

  var w = 600;
  var h = 550;
  var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
  var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);

  chrome.windows.create({ 'url': 'onboarding.html', 'type': 'popup', 'width': w, 'height': h, 'left': left, 'top': top }, function (window) { });
});
```

but I got the below error please help me to reach out this issue.
[image]

Comment: `document.getElementById('spellCheck')` is returning null. Are you sure the `#spellCheck` element exists in the DOM when this code runs?

Comment: Can you show your HTML where you have that element with id `spellCheck`?

Comment: Yes the #spellCheck element is there. Here is the HTML

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
</head>

<body style="width: 400px;">
  <button id="spellCheck">Spell Check</button>
</body>
<script src="popup.js"></script>

</html>`

Comment: add `popup.js` before the `</body>` tag first.

Comment: Yes tried @MohitSharma but still not working

Comment: so you must have to provide minimum reproduction of problem in code snipet or stackblitz so we can check.

Comment: actually this is chrome development tool. So can't add on stackblitz